# Working with Threads inside Flask app context

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, websocket

I'm trying to push an app context to a thread, the thread completes a lengthy task then sends a websocket to alert that it is done. Because I'm using a thread, the socket i've created in javascript that is listening to the 'completed' event is not able to receive it for some reason, when I removed the thread it all worked fine. Here is an attempted solution that I tried but failed:

routes.py

```
import threading
from main import socketio
from flask import current_app

@app.route('/threading')
def threading():
    return render_template('threading.html')

def simulate_long_task(app_context):
        app_context.push() 
        print(app_context)
        print("Long task started...")
        time.sleep(5)  # Simulate a long task (5 seconds)
        print("Long task completed!")
        socketio.emit('completed', {"message": "Hello"})


@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('User connected')

@socketio.on('start_task')
def start_long_task():
    print(current_app.app_context())
    task_thread = threading.Thread(target=simulate_long_task, args=(current_app.app_context(),), daemon=True)
    task_thread.start()
```

threading.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebSocket Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.7.2/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>WebSocket Example</h1>
    <button id="startButton">Start Long Task</button>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect();

        socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log("Connected To Websocket")
            document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
                socket.emit('start_task');
            });
        });

        socket.on('completed', function(data) {
            console.log("Received completed event:", data.message);
            // Handle the data as needed
        });


        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log('Disconnected From Websocket');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Flask-SocketIO for the websockets. The connection of the websocket is working fine, and user is able to connect normally. The only issue is when threads are involved.

Would appreciate any help I could get on this since I've tried pushing the context and tried various solutions from others but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why your application is not working. I notice that you overlay the imported module with the same identifier by defining a `threading` function.

Basically, you don't need the application context to send a message back. This can only become necessary if you access a database within the thread, for example.

If you do need the application context, here is an example.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    current_app, 
    render_template
)
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'
sio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def background_task(app):
    with app.app_context():
        # Work within the application context.
        pass
    sio.sleep(5)
    sio.emit('completed', { 'message': 'Hello' })

@sio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print('User connected')

@sio.on('start-task')
def start_task():
    print('Start background task')
    sio.start_background_task(
        background_task, 
        current_app._get_current_object()
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.run(app)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Websocket Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>WebSocket Example</h1>
    <button id="start-btn">Start Long Task</button>
    <div id="messages"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.7.2/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var socket = io();
            socket.on('connect', () => {
                console.log('Connected to Websocket');
                document
                    .getElementById('start-btn')
                    .addEventListener('click', () => {
                        socket.emit('start-task');
                    });
            });

            socket.on('completed', (data) => {
                console.log(data.message);
            });

            socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                console.log('Disconnected from Websocket');
            });
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much! Been struggling with this for hours!

Comment: When I tried this, the long task is not being executed in the background and its blocking all of the application, is there any other way of doing this to ensure it wont block the flask thread for the application? It's leaving the entirety of the app waiting on the time.sleep(5)

Comment: Running with [`start_background_task`](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_socketio.SocketIO.start_background_task) is the same as your threaded version. The task does not block the application but runs asynchronously. [`sleep`](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_socketio.SocketIO.sleep) of course blocks the thread for specified time. This is intended to simulate the execution time. However, it is still possible to start another task. The application remains usable.